# Configuration VariableName is not available when creating a variable in SQL Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I try to set a variable by using a simple

```
select count(*):
SET NumRows = (
  SELECT 
    count (distinct NBB_CONTRACT_ID) 
  FROM contracts 
  where NBB_T1F2_CP1NAME = 'BNP Paribas Fortis'
)
```

and I get the following error message:

Error running query:

```
[_LEGACY_ERROR_TEMP_DBR_0222] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ExtendedAnalysisException: Configuration NumRows is not available.
```

PLEASE HELP as this driving ME CRAZY!! lol

setting a variable and it doesn't work, in Databricks SQL

Comment: num_rows = spark.sql("""
  SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT NBB_CONTRACT_ID) AS num_rows
  FROM contracts 
  WHERE NBB_T1F2_CP1NAME = 'BNP Paribas Fortis'
""").first()['num_rows']
print(num_rows)

Comment: Can you try the above?

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks SQL, you cannot directly set a variable using the `SET` command within a query. Instead, you can achieve the desired result by executing the query and saving the result into a variable.

I have tried the below approach:

```py
num_rows = spark.sql("""
  SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT NBB_CONTRACT_ID) AS num_rows
  FROM contracts 
  WHERE NBB_T1F2_CP1NAME = 'BNP Paribas Fortis'
""").first()['num_rows']
print(num_rows)
```

**Results:**

```
39
```

In the above code, I executed the query and saved the count result into the **num_rows** variable. `spark.sql(""" ... """)` runs a SQL query using Spark's SQL engine. I selected the count of `distinct` values in the **NBB_CONTRACT_ID** column from the contracts table where **NBB_T1F2_CP1NAME** is equal to '**BNP Paribas Fortis**'. `.first()` retrieves the first row of the query result. `['num_rows']` accesses the value of the num_rows column in the first row.